# I am trying to excute clouser function with controller route list

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to write a code with route controller method.But I am unable to exucte this

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'product.index','do' => function()
{
    $url = parse_url(Request::fullUrl());
    $domain = explode('.', $url['host']);
    $subdomain = $domain[0];
    $name = DB::table('users')->where('name', $subdomain)->first();
    dd($name); 
    if ($name==true) {
    return url('/') . '/?ref=' .$name->id;
}}
]);
```

Comment: that isn't how you define routes ... do you want the route to point to a controller method or do you want to use the closure?

Comment: lagbox@It's Possible  to run clouser function with route controller

Comment: its either the closure or a controller method, which one?

Comment: lagbox 8@I am trying to use this below code in controller

Comment: put it in a controller method and point the route at that controller and method

Comment: you can make middleware for that